# Convert string into date in swift 3

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am using following code to convert string to date but getting date as nil in Swift 3.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy hh:MM" //Your date format
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00") //Current time zone
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "20-07-2017 16:05")
print(date ?? "")
```

Comment: Please review the formatting specification. `mm` and `MM` don't mean what you think they mean. And `hh` isn't correct either.

Comment: Please read [Unicode.org: Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Have you solved your Issue?

Answer (score 0):

you `dateFormatter.dateFormat` is wrong. For month use `MM` and for 24 hour format use `HH`.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" //Your date format
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00") //Current time zone
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "20-07-2017 16:05")
print(date ?? "")
```

Comment: Use this "dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm", notice the mini quotes inside

Comment: @ZonilyJame There is no need to quote the space.

Comment: Oh, are those quotes only for characters?

Comment: @ZonilyJame Quotes are only needed around characters that should be treated as literals when they would otherwise be treated as a format specifier. Punctuation can never be confused as a format specifier so punctuation doesn't need to be quoted. Note how you didn't recommend quoting the hyphen and colon.